# Pronunciation of number 7 in native Korean number

Tags: pronunciation, numbers

I am a bit confused about the pronunciation of number 7 in native Korean number. 
As in the video [here](https://youtu.be/q5HfIVzT6yA?list=PLaGZaJ0OXuoULB6p220wo1QTl3bmXSGum&t=886) (at 27:47), the Korean teacher pronounced it as 일 리 겁. Could anyone confirm if this is correct or am I mishearing it?

Comment: He is pronouncing 7 a little too long and awkwardly. 7 is pronounced like il-gob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this video, the teacher is trying to say the words slowly. 일곱 is an awkward word to say slowly, as it moves from one consonant to another.

I think the '리' you are hearing is just a small 'artefact' of moving from the ㄹ to the ㄱ while keeping the sound voiced all the way through. You're not imagining it, but it's not significant either. Try to hear it as just two syllables: '일 - 겁'.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like he's just dragging out the ㄹ

Answer (score 1):

Teacher is correct. That sound is 7(일곱). Just accept his pronunciation.